# How to draw a square wave?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks

Everything is in the title...

I'm trying to draw a simple `square wave` , but I'm reading that `tikz` cannot draw the vertical line of the discontinuity...

Is there a way to overpass this ? `PSTricks` maybe ?

This is what I'm trying to represent :

[image: what I'm trying to do]

Comment: Seriously? I would be very surprised if `tikz` wasn't able to draw vertical lines... What might be true is that you will need to draw each segment separately (I unfortunately don't know `tikz`, otherwise I would propose an answer).

Comment: Yes, tikz can actually draw vertical lines in general ^^, but not for a piece-defined function...
At least, it what's I saw on the net...

Comment: ?? TikZ can certainly draw this.  What might be trickier is to draw it *as the graph of a function*.  A simple `\draw (0,0) \foreach \k in {0,...,5} { let \n1={-2*mod(\k,2) + 1} in -- ++(0,\n1) -- ++(1,0)};` will draw the wave.

Comment: @AndrewStacey: Your method requires the use of the `calc` library

Comment: @KevinC True, but then I left it as a comment to show that it was possible and that I felt that the question needed making more precise to show where the problem lay, not to provide an answer.

Comment: A square wave doesn't *have* vertical lines. (No function does.)

Comment: @Kaz Try with an oscilloscope hence the name *wave* :)

Comment: @percusse My analog scope has a 1Khz square vave test signal point right on the front panel where you can attach a probe. All you see is is flat tops and bottoms.

Comment: @Kaz It is not analog enough if you know what I mean

Comment: @LoopSpace I used your code to [plot this, and got this](http://imgur.com/IPtEb5o). But I wanted to to have step 1(amplitude as it is after z=L). Can I have it in the begining? Means same starting point as the end points.

Comment: @LoopSpace This is the code  `\draw[ultra thick,cyan] (0,0) \foreach \k in {0,...,8} { let \n1={-2*mod(\k,2) + 1.0} in -- ++(0,\n1) -- ++(1,0)};`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Without TikZ.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(9,3)   
    \psaxes{->}(0,0)(-1,-1)(8.5,2.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \multips(0,0)(2,0){4}{\psline[linecolor=red](0,2)(1,2)(1,0)(2,0)(2,2)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: OP had pstricks tag `With PSTricks` would suffice rather than a negation.

Answer (score 27):

A suggestion with `pgfplots`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=10cm,
height=4cm,
x axis line style={-stealth},
y axis line style={-stealth},
title={Square wave},
xticklabels={},
ymax = 1.5,xmax=7.5,
axis lines*=center,
ytick={0.5,1},
xlabel={Time $\rightarrow$},
ylabel={Amplitude},
xlabel near ticks,
ylabel near ticks]
\addplot+[thick,mark=none,const plot]
coordinates
{(0,0) (0,1) (1,0) (2,1) (3,0) (4,1) (5,0) (6,1) (7,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 22):

Here's one possibility using TikZ and a simple `\foreach` loop (I didn't drew the axes since the problem seemed to be the wave itself):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \ini [evaluate=\ini as \inieval using 2*\ini] in {0,...,6}
\draw[ultra thick,cyan] (\inieval,0) -- ++(0,1) -| (\inieval+1,0) -- (\inieval+2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason that you use `evaluate` instead of `{0,2,...,12}`?

Comment: @Tobi I was going to give a more general approach, allowing to control the amplitude and the time interval of each pulse. Finally I went for a simple direct answer so, in this case, the use of `evaluate` seems superfluous; in the more general setting (that can easily be obtained with minor changes from my code) I had originally devised, it could be useful.

Comment: Just a naive question, if I would like to start from top line instead of fall, how to go about? I am just trying without any success(as I didn't understand your code)

Answer (score 16):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\makeatletter
\def\func{ x T1 gt { 
      T1 yVal \tx@ScreenCoor 
      2 copy 4 2 roll L pop yVal L 
      /yVal yVal 0 gt {0}{yMax}ifelse def 
      /T1 T1 T0 add def } if yVal }
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\psset{xAxisLabel=t, yAxisLabel=U}
\begin{psgraph}{->}(0,0)(0,-0.5)(11,1.5){12cm}{5cm}
\psplot[plotpoints=200,linecolor=red,linewidth=2pt]{0}{10}
  [ /yMax 1 def /T0 1 def /T1 T0 def /yVal yMax def ]{ \func }
\psplot[plotpoints=500,linecolor=blue,linewidth=2pt]{0}{10}
  [ /yMax 0.75 def /T0 1.5 def /T1 T0 def /yVal yMax def ]{ \func }
\end{psgraph}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 14):

<strike>Cheating with `pgfplots` (verticals are not true verticals :) but gets better with increased sample number).</strike>

Jake has brought me to my senses :)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[grid=both,xmin=0,width=7cm,height=4cm,
title=Square Wave,xlabel={Time$\rightarrow$},ylabel=Amplitude]
\addplot+[thick,const plot, no marks,samples at={0,1,...,10}] {(mod(x,2)>0?0:1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No need to cheat: `\addplot+[thick,const plot, no marks,samples at={0,1,...,10}] {(mod(x,2)>0?0:1)};` (with true vertical lines!)

Comment: @Jake */facepalm*....

Answer (score 9):

Just for the (my) fun of it, a fairly automatic TikZ solution which also incorporates shifts and the duty factor:

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\mydutyfactor}{0.11}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myperiod}{1.5}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myxlowborder}{-4}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myxtopborder}{3}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myamplitude}{2.1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myxshift}{0.3}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myyshift}{0.4}
\newcommand{\myxlabel}{$t[s]$}
\newcommand{\myylabel}{$U[V]$}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[thick,-latex] (\myxlowborder,0) -- (\myxtopborder+0.5,0) node[right] {\myxlabel};
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myminy}{floor(\myyshift-\myamplitude/2)}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mymaxy}{ceil(\myyshift+\myamplitude/2)}
    \draw[thick,-latex] (0,\myminy) -- (0,\mymaxy+0.5) node[above] {\myylabel};
    \foreach \x in {\myxlowborder,...,\myxtopborder} \draw (\x,0.03) -- (\x,-0.03) node[below ] {\x};
    \foreach \y in {\myminy,...,\mymaxy} \draw (0.03,\y) -- (-0.03,\y) node[left] {\y};
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myminindex}{ceil((\myxlowborder-\myxshift)/\myperiod)-1}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mymaxindex}{floor((\myxtopborder-\myxshift)/\myperiod)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\mylowlevel}{\myyshift-\myamplitude/2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myhihlevel}{\myyshift+\myamplitude/2}
    \clip (\myxlowborder,\myminy) rectangle (\myxtopborder,\mymaxy);
    \foreach \x in {\myminindex,...,\mymaxindex} \draw[red] (\x*\myperiod+\myxshift,\mylowlevel) -- (\x*\myperiod+\myxshift,\myhihlevel) -- (\x*\myperiod+\myxshift+\mydutyfactor*\myperiod,\myhihlevel) -- (\x*\myperiod+\myxshift+\mydutyfactor*\myperiod,\mylowlevel) -- (\x*\myperiod+\myxshift+\myperiod,\mylowlevel);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 5):

using [gnuplottex](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/gnuplottex) package with `-shell-escape` enabled  and `gnuplot 4.4`

[image]

```
% Code compiled with pdflatex engine via frozen texlive 2012 on Linux 
% Need "-shell-escape" enabled and gnuplot 4.4 
\documentclass[preview=true,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{gnuplottex} % http://www.ctan.org/pkg/gnuplottex
\begin{document} 
\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=epslatex,terminaloptions=color]
# xy co-ordinates range
xmin=-19;xmax=6;ymin=-1;ymax=1;
unset border   # border off
unset xtics    # remove xaxis tics
set ytics ("0" -1, "0.5" 0, "1" 1) nomirror  # remove rightside yaxis ticks
set samples 300  # number of sample points
set arrow from xmin,ymin to xmax,ymin linewidth 1.5 # x-axis 
set arrow from xmin+0.15,ymin to xmin+0.15,ymax+0.2 linewidth 1.5 # y-axis 
set arrow from -5,ymin-0.1 to -3,ymin-0.1 # Time arrow
set title 'Square wave'
set xlabel "Time" 
set ylabel "Amplitude"  
# based on "Other definitions" at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_wave
plot [xmin:xmax] [ymin:ymax] sgn(sin(x)) linecolor 3 linewidth 3  notitle;
\end{gnuplot}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\usepackage[miktex]{gnuplottex}` with `-shell-escape` enabled using `pdflatex`

Answer (score 3):

Using TikZ decorations (this example is from [TikZ manual](https://pgf-tikz.github.io/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf)):

```
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{example}{initial}
{
    \state{initial}[width=10pt]{
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{5pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{5pt}{5pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{5pt}{-5pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{10pt}{-5pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{10pt}{0pt}}
    }
    \state{final}
    {
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
    }
}

\tikz
{
    \draw[decorate,decoration=example](0,0)-- (3,0);
    \draw[red,decorate,decoration=example] (0,0)to [out=45,in=135] (3,0);
}
```

[image: tikz-decorator]