# Creating colorful plot using latex terminal of gnuplot?

Tags: pdftex, color, gnuplot

Most output terminals of `gnuplot` draw different lines in a plot in different colors.

I'm trying to create a plot inside my PDF document using `gnuplot`'s LaTeX terminal and the lines are only distinguishable by linestyle.

What do I need to do to get the lines colored?

I use `pdflatex`.

From this example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[miktex]{gnuplottex}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=latex]
plot [0:2*pi] sin(x) title 'Sine', cos(x) title 'Cosine'
\end{gnuplot}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I get this result:

[image]

@texenthusiast provides part of the solution: set the options `[terminal=epslatex,terminaloptions=color]` when using `gnuplot`.

And don't forget to load `epstopdf` in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{epstopdf}
```

The lines in the plot will now be colored but still have different styles.

[image]

To give them the same style you can now use something like

```
set style line 1 linecolor rgb '#0060ad' linetype 1 linewidth 2
set style line 2 linecolor rgb '#dd181f' linetype 1 linewidth 2
plot [0:2*pi] sin(x) with lines ls 1 title 'Sine', cos(x) with lines ls 2 title 'Cosine'
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: may be `terminal=pdf` should give default gnuplot colors

Comment: @texenthusiast It surely will, but then gnuplot does the typesetting instead of TeX, so that TeX macros in labels or titles will fail.

Comment: Sorry, a bit rusty,  Use `[terminal=epslatex,terminaloptions=color]` which can get [TeX typset the labels and title](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/113326/15717) as @Marco said.

Comment: With `latex` terminal export it gives out picture environment without any colors and does not understand the default colors of gnuplot. I will have to see if gnuplot can do it or exported .tex file has to manually edited to add color packages and userdefined colors

Comment: To get the same line type for all curves, use the `solid` terminal option, i.e. `[terminal=epslatex, terminaloptions=color solid]`. And in case you ever want colored text, for the `epslatex` terminal there is an additional `colortext` option to enable this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Out of the many( `latex`, `tex`, `epslatex`,`pstricks`
`pdf` and `lua/tikz`) `gnuplot` terminal exports available `epslatex` seems reasonable.

Using `[terminal=epslatex,terminaloptions=color]` seems to be optimal since `.eps` plot is taken from `gnuplot` and `TeX` is used to typeset `text in labels/titles` to give nice consistency. But for more options [gnuplottex](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/gnuplottex/gnuplottex.pdf) might give details.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[miktex]{gnuplottex} % for MiKTeX,`pdflatex -shell-escape` enabled 
%\usepackage{gnuplottex} I have used this line to compile on TeXLive 2013
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{epstopdf} % for MiKTeX,`pdflatex -shell-escape` enabled
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=epslatex,terminaloptions=color]
plot [0:2*pi] sin(x) title 'Sine', cos(x) title 'Cosine'
\end{gnuplot}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Example: [How to draw a square wave?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/113326/15717)

Comment: For completeness: Gnuplot 4.6 provides also a `cairolatex` terminal (either with `eps` or `pdf` output) and a `context` terminal.