# How to draw randomly spaced square wave

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, random

I am new to tikz and am not familiar with nomenclature so please excuse my raw expression here.

I need to say a non-periodic square wave. I saw this post [How to draw a square wave?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113046/how-to-draw-a-square-wave/113051#113051) which talks about a periodic sq wave. 
Right now my solution comprises of drawing individual line segments and that taking too much time.

Is there a faster way of doing this

So Far:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Grid+Irregular wave}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [black] (-5.0,0) -- (-4.75,0);
    \draw [black] (-4.75,0) -- (-4.75,1);
    \draw [black] (-4.75,1) -- (-4.5,1);
    \draw [black] (-4.5,1) -- (-4.5,0);   
    \draw [black] (-4.5,0) -- (-4.0,0);
    \draw [black] (-4.0,0) -- (-4.,1);
    \draw [black] (-4.0,1) -- (-3.0,1);
    \draw [black] (-3.0,1) -- (-3.0,0);    
    \draw [black] (-3.0,0) -- (-2.5,0);
    \draw [black] (-2.5,0) -- (-2.5,1);
    \draw [black] (-2.5,1) -- (-2.0,1);
    \draw [black] (-2.0,1) -- (-2.0,0);
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{center}
 \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have so far?

Comment: actually, i just want to show a non-periodic wave , so the transitions can be at any random time instance…..so the values that I used in my code are not important for me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply randomize the lengths of rising and falling edge locations

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) --(1,0)|- ++(rnd,1)
     \foreach \x in {1,...,10}{-|++(rnd,-1) -| ++(rnd,1)}
     -| ++(rnd,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]