# LaTeX error with running gnuplot example on Windows 7

Tags: gnuplot

When trying to run the example code below found at [How to draw a square wave?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113046/how-to-draw-a-square-wave/113326#113326), I get the error: "LaTeX Error: File `gnuplot3-gnuplottex-fig1' not found", although I am seeing the eps file created in my folder.

I followed the steps found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/242132/plot-file-could-not-be-opened) to include the `--shell-escape` in the PDFLaTeX option in WinEdt.  I still have the error.  I am however able to run other simple gnuplot code like that found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/242132/plot-file-could-not-be-opened).

Can you tell me why I am getting this error although the eps file is created?  Thanks.

Here is the original code:

```
% Code compiled with pdflatex engine via frozen texlive 2012 on Linux 
% Need "-shell-escape" enabled and gnuplot 4.4 
\documentclass[preview=true,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{gnuplottex} % http://www.ctan.org/pkg/gnuplottex
\begin{document} 
\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=epslatex,terminaloptions=color]
# xy co-ordinates range
xmin=-19;xmax=6;ymin=-1;ymax=1;
unset border   # border off
unset xtics    # remove xaxis tics
set ytics ("0" -1, "0.5" 0, "1" 1) nomirror  # remove rightside yaxis ticks
set samples 300  # number of sample points
set arrow from xmin,ymin to xmax,ymin linewidth 1.5 # x-axis 
set arrow from xmin+0.15,ymin to xmin+0.15,ymax+0.2 linewidth 1.5 # y-axis 
set arrow from -5,ymin-0.1 to -3,ymin-0.1 # Time arrow
set title 'Square wave'
set xlabel "Time" 
set ylabel "Amplitude"  
# based on "Other definitions" at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_wave
plot [xmin:xmax] [ymin:ymax] sgn(sin(x)) linecolor 3 linewidth 3  notitle;
\end{gnuplot}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `pdflatex` or equivalent to generate PDF directly, it won't include PS (or EPS, for that matter). Formats acceptable are PDF, PNG, JPEG.